# Usar símbolo numa input text, e desaparecer quando se escreve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma caixa de texto, uma *input type text*. E queria inserir uma imagem no canto, por exemplo, uma lupa. E quando o utilizador começar a escrever, essa lupa desapareça. É possível fazer isso em Javascript?

```
<input type="text" name="search">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar uma `background-image` que muda de posição (desaparece) no `focus`:

```
input {
    background-image: url(http://www.levenmetwater.nl/static/global/images/icon-search.png);

input:focus {
    background-position: -20px center;
    /* ou pode mesmo removê-la com: 'background-image: none;' */
```

Assim quando o `input` recebe o `focus`, a imagem de fundo sai do input `20px` à esquerda. Quando o `input` perde o `focus`, então a primeira regra pervalece. A vantagem desta abordagem é que usa somente CSS.

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/26z2v/)

Exemplo mais simples sem animações: http://jsfiddle.net/GFsLa/1/

Comment: Muito bom! obrigado!

Comment: @pc_oc, fico contente de poder ajudar.

Comment: Ok, a resposta é válida, porém, quando tiro o foco do input, o texto sobrepõe a imagem.

Comment: @ViniciusLima, pode mudar o `text-indent` para não ficar or cima da imagem. Exemplo: __http://jsfiddle.net/ysB9P/__ Também é possível ir via javascript/jQuery mas CSS é melhor. Exemplo: __http://jsfiddle.net/Gg9nf/__

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do `@Sergio` é um jeito bem fácil e usual de se fazer. Porém, eu usava bastante colocar a imagem fora do `input` e colocar uma margem negativa, assim ela da impressão que está dentro. Ex:

```
<style>
  .margin_neg{margin-left-40px;}
</style>    
<input type="text" value="" class="input" id="input1"/><img src="Exemplo.img" class="margin_neg"/>
```

Ai quando vc começar a escrever basta dar um `hide()` com jquery, ou `display:none` como você preferir. Ex:

```
$('.margin_neg').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Além de `background-image`, quando o que quiser que apareça seja texto e tenha interesse que o conteúdo seja lido por leitores de tela, é interessante usar `placeholder`. O texto de `placeholder` irá aparecer enquanto nada estiver digitado e desaparecer der foco no elemento e começar a escrever.

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Pesquisar no site"/>
```

[Visualize no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fititnt/L9y9w/).

Como IEs antigos não suportam placeholder, aqui tem polyfills em Web Forms : input placeholder https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

> Nota: a diferença entre uso de `placeholder` e `imagem via CSS` é que o primeiro caso é indicado quando você quer que o conteúdo seja lido por ferramentas de suporte a leitura de tela usada por pessoas de baixa visão ou cegas, e o segundo é indicado quando a anotação é meramente visual e não haverá prejuízo em ser ignorada,

Comment: sim, mas não é isso que procuro :)

Comment: @Emerson, boa informação mas não para este post.

Comment: O problema é que pessoas que não sabem de `placeholder` podem ver esse post e usar CSS `content: "Pesquisar no site";` para algo que tem implicações de acessibilidade. Essa não é a resposta exata para esse post, mas é uma resposta complementar pertinente, em especial um caso extremamente parecido que envolve perda de acessibilidade mas visualmente aparenta estar OK. Acessibilidade importa.