# É possível inserir um SVG como value em uma tag input?

Tags: html, css, input, svg

Tenho o botão abaixo e o que quero é que ao invés do nome "Ir", eu possa utilizar uma imagem, seja ela em SVG ou mesmo algo do Font Awesome. Como proceder nesse caso?

Desde já, grato!

```css
input {background:#B80000; color:#fff; font-size:13px; height:27.7px!important; margin:0 3px; width:15%; font-family:Segoe UI; text-transform:uppercase; border:none}
```

```html
<input class='follow-by-email-submit' type='submit' value='Ir'/>
```

Comment: Não seria com `background-image:url('imagem.svg')`?

Comment: Use: input:before{content: "caminho/imagen.svg: ";}

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Usar símbolo numa input text, e desaparecer quando se escreve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5003/usar-s%c3%admbolo-numa-input-text-e-desaparecer-quando-se-escreve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em um botão usando `input` você não vai conseguir isso. Em vez de `input`, use `button`, porque ele suporta outros tipos de elementos.

Então você pode usar [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) para incluir um ícone ao botão:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button class='follow-by-email-submit'>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
```

Ou pode usar uma imagem qualquer:

```html
<button class='follow-by-email-submit'>
   <img height="30" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" />
</button>
```

> E não precisa incluir o atributo `type="submit"` ao `button`. Por padrão
>   ele já é do tipo `submit`.

Comment: +1 - vale lembrar que  sempre tem a "gambiarra" do "label for" (esconde o elemento original, enfia um label como "controle remoto" daquele elemento). É preferivel nativo sempre que possível, conforme respondido. (um uso válido seria um SVG num checkbox, que nao tem equivalente como o button)

Comment: É verdade. Vlw!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Outra opção, que por sinal é até mais semântica, seria colocar o SVG no `<label>`, fazendo dessa forma:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='25' height='25' viewBox='0 0 25 25' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cpath d='M16.036 18.455l2.404-2.405 5.586 5.587-2.404 2.404zM8.5 2C12.1 2 15 4.9 15 8.5S12.1 15 8.5 15 2 12.1 2 8.5 4.9 2 8.5 2zm0-2C3.8 0 0 3.8 0 8.5S3.8 17 8.5 17 17 13.2 17 8.5 13.2 0 8.5 0zM15 16a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 1 1-2 0'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") center / contain no-repeat;
}

input {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="button" value="Entrar">
</label>
```

---

Vou dar uma resposta diferente da que tem na pergunta marcada como duplicado, pois acredito que ela vai te atender melhor.

Primeiro para conhecimento: Não é todo `<input>` que aceita pseudo elemento `::after` e `::before` como vc pode ver nessa pergunta. [Os pseudo elementos ::after e ::before funcionam em quais input types](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263040/os-pseudo-elementos-after-e-before-funcionam-em-quais-input-types)

Então para o exemplo vou usar o `<button>`

Agora a técnica usando o `content` do pseudo elemento `::after` para colocar o simbolo do **Font Awesome** que vc quiser.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.awesome {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: brown;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.awesome::after {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.awesome:hover::after {
    font-size: 24px;
    content: "\f1b9";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<button class="awesome"></button>
```

**OBS1:** Para usar o **Font Awesome** no `content:""` vc precisa usar o valor Unicode do caractere, se usar a classe padrão do Font Awesome não vai dar certo.

Comment: Pessoal, todos os comentários foram extremamente úteis. Basicamente, todos eles funcionaram. Optei por utilizar como o 'button' que realmente caiu como uma luva. Eu havia desconfiado que, de fato, o input não aceitaria algo nessas condições. Obrigado a todos! Deus abençoe!

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar IMG dentro da TAG **button**:

```
<form name="sender" method="get">
    <button><img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/x11.svg" /></button>
</form>
```

Se o BUTTON não funcionar como SUBMIT pode usar JAVASCRIPT:

```
<button onclick="document.sender.submit()"><img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/x11.svg" /></button>
```

Se for um SVG desenhado pelo HTML:

```html
<button><svg width="64" height="64">
  <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="yellow" />
</svg></button>
```

Vale lembrar que a posição X e Y do círculo tem que ser metade da largura e altura do SVG para centralizar, sendo o R o tamanho dimensional dele.